# Show facebook chat bot has seen message

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

**How can I send a facebook messenger response that acknowledges seeing the input but does not deliver a message?**

---

Use Case:

I am attempting to improve my chat bot by better handling of multiple rapid inputs.
For example:

> User: Order a pizza.
>   Bot: What toppings would you like?
>   User: cheees
>   User: cheese

It usually happens if the user misspelled a word and quickly sends a corrected spelling as in the example.
The bot currently processes the first input of `cheees` and prepares a response.
Then processes the second input of `cheese` as if it is an answer to the undelivered response.

So I am detecting if a second input is received before delivering the first in order to cancel that response, but I want to at least show that the first input was seen while waiting for the second input's response to be delivered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible. There are [sender actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/sender-actions). You're looking for `mark_seen` what exactly makes messages being seen by your bot.

I would have several recommendations here:

- Always mark messages as seen. From the user perspective it shows that there is someone on the other side.
- Prior to sending a message, you should consider sending a typing indicator for a second. This is how the user is used to see chat with his friends.
- You could also wait one or two seconds before processing the user input if you receive something else.

We've build in these solutions into [Amio Bot Builder](https://github.com/amio-io/amio-chatbot-builder-js). Feel free to use it or copy it.